# Convert string to real HTML in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I received information from an API which comes with HTML. What happens is, when I try to display the information in the code, it transforms the HTML in a string and doesn't read as real HTML.
I search a lot and all I saw was the method of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but I also saw some reviews and comments about it and I don't want to use it if exists another solution.   Also, I tried to use `Fragmant` but not success.

Below is my render() code:

```
return (
  <div>
    {models.map(model => (
      <a href="/sofa">
        <div className="Parcelas" key={model.id}>
          <img
            src={"url" + model.image}
            className="ParcImage"
            alt="sofa"
          />
          <h1>Sofá {model.name}</h1>
          <h2>
            1,200<span>€</span>
          </h2>

          <p className="Features">{model.description}</p>

          <button className="Botao">
            <p className="MostraDepois">Ver Detalhes</p>
            <span>+</span>
          </button>
          <img src="../../img/points.svg" className="Decoration" alt="points" />
        </div>
      </a>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Here's an image showing:

[image: I want this in HTML]

Comment: Could you give us more information, like how you models object looks like or an example screenshot?

Comment: @MaddEye I edited the question

Comment: Did you find a safe solution for this? Some threads have suggested libraries but they don't mention anything about the safety.

Comment: I've used the solution below that Tholle talked about. Idk about security honestly @Omar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have html in a string, you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) to render it as html.

```
return (
  <div>
    {models.map(model => (
      <a href="/sofa">
        <div className="Parcelas" key={model.id}>
          <img
            src={"url" + model.image}
            className="ParcImage"
            alt="sofa"
          />
          <h1>Sofá {model.name}</h1>
          <h2>
            1,200<span>€</span>
          </h2>

          <p
            className="Features"
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: model.description }}
          />

          <button className="Botao">
            <p className="MostraDepois">Ver Detalhes</p>
            <span>+</span>
          </button>
          <img src="../../img/points.svg" className="Decoration" alt="points" />
        </div>
      </a>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the text you're trying to append to the node is no escaped like this:

```
model: {
  description: '&lt;h1&gt;Hi there!&lt;/h1&gt;'
}
```

Instead of this:

```
model: {
  description: '<h1>Hi there!</h1>'
}
```

if is escaped you should convert it from your server-side.

if you can't try something like this:

```
<p className="Features">{model.description.fromCharCode(183)}</p>
```

Another option is a combination of ReactHtmlParser and unescapingHtml:

```
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser";

let model = [
  {
    description: "<h1>Hello There</h1>"
  },
  {
    description: "&lt;h1&gt;Hello There&lt;/h1&gt;"
  }
];

function App() {
  function unescapeHTML(html) {
    var escapeEl = document.createElement("textarea");
    escapeEl.innerHTML = html;
    return escapeEl.textContent;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {model.map(des => {
        return ReactHtmlParser(unescapeHTML(des.description));
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thw HTML comes from the API response, how do I do that `model: {}`? Also, the `fromCharCode(183)` says error `it's not a function`

Comment: it's simply a view of your possible model json. I editet the answer with an runable example for a working solution